# Need assistance with a for loop

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I'd like to know if there's a way I can have the below code increment the {{routemapnumber}} value by 5 each time it is listed. So the first {{routemapnumber}} value would be 5 then the other would be 10 etc.  I think  a for loop would work but Im having issues with syntax.

```
route-map RDS_FILTER permit {{routemapnumber}}
 match ip address {{item.aclnumber}}
 set ip next-hop verify-availability 10.4.21.157 1 track {{item.slanumber}}
 set ip next-hop 192.168.2.58
route-map RDS_FILTER permit {{routemapnumber}}
 match ip address 109
 set ip next-hop verify-availability 10.4.21.157 1 track 1
 set ip next-hop 192.168.2.58
route-map RDS_FILTER permit {{routemapnumber}}
 match ip address 108
route-map RDS_FILTER permit {{routemapnumber}}
match ip address 107
 set ip next-hop 192.168.0.2
route-map RDS_FILTER permit {{routemapnumber}
```

Comment: i am not sure you can use a for loop, the rest of the text you have in your file is not repeating itself. try to hardcode the increments, ie use: `{{routemapnumber + 5}}`, in next place: `{{routemapnumber + 10}}` etc

Comment: That's the problem Ive been having. Ive noticed that the for loop doesn't work with additional text below. Hard coding is my alternative but the amount of variables are dynamic making that option sub par.

Answer (score 0):

if there are not many lines, i would go with hardcoding the increments, for example:

```
route-map RDS_FILTER permit {{routemapnumber}}
 match ip address
 set ip next-hop verify-availability 10.4.21.157 1 track
 set ip next-hop 192.168.2.58
route-map RDS_FILTER permit {{routemapnumber + 10}}
 match ip address 109
 set ip next-hop verify-availability 10.4.21.157 1 track 1
 set ip next-hop 192.168.2.58
route-map RDS_FILTER permit {{routemapnumber + 15}}
 match ip address 108
route-map RDS_FILTER permit {{routemapnumber + 20}}
match ip address 107
 set ip next-hop 192.168.0.2
route-map RDS_FILTER permit {{routemapnumber + 25}}
```

if this is not a good option for you, you can add some math logic to the template, by using the `set` statement to increment the variable, right before you print it with:

`{% set routemapnumber = routemapnumber + 5 %}`

full example:

```
route-map RDS_FILTER permit {{routemapnumber}}
 match ip address
 set ip next-hop verify-availability 10.4.21.157 1 track
 set ip next-hop 192.168.2.58
route-map RDS_FILTER permit {% set routemapnumber = routemapnumber + 5 %}{{routemapnumber}}
 match ip address 109
 set ip next-hop verify-availability 10.4.21.157 1 track 1
 set ip next-hop 192.168.2.58
route-map RDS_FILTER permit {% set routemapnumber = routemapnumber + 5 %}{{routemapnumber}}
 match ip address 108
route-map RDS_FILTER permit {% set routemapnumber = routemapnumber + 5 %}{{routemapnumber}}
match ip address 107
 set ip next-hop 192.168.0.2
route-map RDS_FILTER permit {% set routemapnumber = routemapnumber + 5 %}{{routemapnumber}}
```